# sql query to fetch records between current date and minimum date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing this sql query but it says now  non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.Where is the mistake??

```
 SELECT dr.*
 from daily_data_reading dr
 where pod_id='01611152005960'
   and DAILY_READING_DATE BETWEEN to_date(' min(daily_reading_date)','DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')+ interval '1' day
     AND to_date('trunc(SYSDATE) 23:59:59','DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') + interval '1' day;
```

Comment: `to_date` gets a string, and this string should represent a date; for example, '01/01/2016'. I believe you should post you data structure, sample data and desired result, explaining what you need to do.

Comment: i want to get all the records for that pod_id between current date and minimum date.How can i achieve that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `to_date()` in the wrong way

It makes no sense to call `to_date()` on a `date` value to convert that `date` value to a `date`.

Also `to_date()` expects a string formatted as a valid date.
Neither `'min(daily_reading_date)'` nor `'trunc(SYSDATE) 23:59:59'` is a valid date string.

So

```
to_date('min(daily_reading_date)','DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')+ interval '1' day
```

needs to be:

```
min(daily_reading_date) + interval '1' day
```

And

```
to_date('trunc(SYSDATE) 23:59:59','DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') + interval '1' day
```

should be:

```
AND trunc(SYSDATE) + interval '1' day
```

So your complete query should be:

```
SELECT dr.*
from daily_data_reading dr
where pod_id = '01611152005960'
  and DAILY_READING_DATE BETWEEN min(daily_reading_date) + interval '1' day
                             AND trunc(SYSDATE) + interval '1' day;
```

But the above query will just trigger the next error: you can't use `min(daily_reading_date)` without applying a `group by` clause.

But you should ask a new question for that - **including** sample data and table definitions.